# Timeline in edit video

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html5-canvas, html5-video

I have a task create a timeline in editvideo in react such as https://clideo.com/editor/ or https://www.canva.com/design/ .(I just need the timeline cursor is run correct with time video). Can you can give a idea to do it, thanks you every much.I was trying do this by many way such as "setinterval", "window.requestAnimationFrame",.. but it failed

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is a general idea of how you might implement a timeline in a video editor using React.

The main idea is to use the HTML5 video element and its APIs to manipulate and keep track of the current video time. You can then reflect this time on your custom timeline. Here is a simplified version of how you can do it:

1. **Setting Up Video Player:** Firstly, you need to have a `<video>` element in your React component to play the video. Here, you would use the `ref` attribute to create a reference to the video element. The reference would allow you to access the video APIs directly.

```
<video ref={videoRef} src={videoURL} controls />
```

2. **Setting Up Timeline:** You would need an HTML element that acts as a timeline. This could be a range input (`<input type="range" />`). This element would also need a ref so that you can manipulate it.

```
<input ref={timelineRef} type="range" min={0} step={0.01} />
```

3. **Synchronizing Video and Timeline:** Use the video APIs to update the timeline as the video is playing. You could do this in the `useEffect` hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const video = videoRef.current;
    const timeline = timelineRef.current;

    function handleTimeUpdate() {
        timeline.value = video.currentTime;
    }

    if(video) {
        video.addEventListener("timeupdate", handleTimeUpdate);
    }

    return () => {
        if(video) {
            video.removeEventListener("timeupdate", handleTimeUpdate);
        }
    };
}, []);
```

In the above code, we add a 'timeupdate' event listener to the video. This event is fired when the current time of the video changes (i.e., as the video is playing). When this event is fired, we update the timeline's value to be the video's current time.

Please note, you should update the `max` value of the `input` range to be the `duration` of the video. This should be done once the metadata of the video has been loaded.

4. **Handling Timeline Interactions:** When the user interacts with the timeline (i.e., clicks and drags the timeline cursor), you want to update the video's current time. You can do this by listening for the `change` event or `input` event on the range input.

```
function handleTimelineChange(e) {
    videoRef.current.currentTime = e.target.value;
}

<input ref={timelineRef} type="range" min={0} step={0.01} onChange={handleTimelineChange} />
```

This is a basic idea of how you can create a timeline that is in sync with the video's current time. This approach is quite simplified and may not cover all the requirements you might have for your video editor. You would need to expand on this to cater to more complex functionalities.

Also, please remember to handle possible null references in the actual implementation. The above code snippets are only to illustrate the concept and may not be complete or entirely functional.

In addition, this approach does not depend on `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame`. The HTML5 video element's 'timeupdate' event automatically provides us with the current time of the video.